# my config.js file is not being recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, import, module

In my index.js file, I have `const config = require('config');` written as one of the first lines.

And I have a file in my project folder called config.js

But I keep having my console tell my that it  `Cannot find module 'config'`

My config file is this basically:

```
module.exports = {
    'secretKey': 'mySecretCode12232',
    'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
};
```

This doesn't make any sense it should be working.

Comment: You're path to the config file could be off. Could you post the project directory tree?

Comment: I fixed it, nevermind

Comment: thanks for helping tho

Comment: No problem. It's always nice to answer your own questions =)

Answer (score 0):

```
const config = require( path.join(__dirname, 'config'+'.js' ) );
```

I also have own function which loads atomaticaly from specified subdirectory at it's definition, it saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't provide any path selector in the require statement (eg. `require('./config'))`, your code will search for the package named `config` and fail as it cannot find this specific one, as require will assume that it was the package name that was provided (and will start searching e.g. in your `node_modules` etc. - search path for it is not a trivial topic :) ).

If you want to require the module from another file, you have to provide a correct path to it, so assuming your `config.js` resides in the same catalog as your other file, the correct statement would be:

`const config = require('./config'); // Extension can be omitted`